# How can I get pictures shared with my account in Google Photos

Tags: picasa, google-photos

I want to create an app that will display pictures and videos shared with a specific Google Photo account.

I thought on implementing it by authenticate using `Google OAuth2` and then to get the shared pictures and videos via `API` call.

The problem is I don't seem to find any API for the new `Google Photo`, only for `Picasa` and even then it more about managing the photos and nothing about getting pictures and videos shared with my account.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to access "Shared Albums" on Google Photos using the Picasa Web Albums API.